# Performance difference between MySQL and MSSQL with multiple short select query's

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, select

Recently my work migrated from MySQL to MSSQL.

One of our applications is doing an select query on a relative small table which has a between 600 / 700 rows.
The aTable columns are:

```
[aIDNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[aDate] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
[aDayNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[aNumber] [numeric](4, 2) NOT NULL
```

With indexes on aIDNumber and aDate.

The select query is:

```
SELECT SUM([aNumber]) as [total]
    FROM [aTable]
    WHERE
    [aIDNumber] = 59
    AND [aDate] = (SELECT MAX([aDate]) as [aDate] FROM [aTable]
    WHERE [aIDNumber] = 59 and [aDayNumber] = 3
    AND [aDate] <= '2021-03-31' )
    AND [aDayNumber] = 3;
```

Unfortunately changing the query is out of my hands.

The problem is that this select query is run about 800 times in a short interval.
The parameters change for the query: Such as aIDNumber and aDate It collects records for 40 id's and 20 days.

When you run it once, it is super fast.
But when run 800 times in sequence the server starts to be very slow and total execution time is 1 minute or more.
Other query's are running just fine, it is just this repetitive query which starts to get slow.

On MySQL we didn't have this issue. The same query still runs super fast.

The database itself is hosted on a Windows server with 16GB of ram.
No updates or other connections are happening during our tests.

Any suggestions?

We tried to change the query, put it in a view, stored procedure.

We are working on accessing the data differently and changing the need for the 800 sequential query's.

However one would expect that MSSQL can handle this rather easily?

Easy steps to reproduce:
An MSSQL server database.
1 table with just 1 record.
Now run a select query on this table more than 800 times in 1 connection and batch and MSSQL gets slow.

Comment: The query is bad to begin with, not super fast in both databases. Without indexes, the server will have to scan the full table in both cases. We can't guess what server each database used either, how many connections access the same table, whether there are attempts to *update* it, resulting in blocking.

Comment: Besides, why do you want to execute the *same* query 800 times if the results are the same? What are you trying to calculate? If the results aren't the same, it means the table is getting updated by other connections that may be locking it. If you execute it 800 times for different values, don't. Execute it just once to calculate all the results.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a running total per day? In both databases this is done using a single query with `SUM() OVER()...` and a Calendar table. This will generate results for *millions* of rows. 800 is no data at all even for the smallest database. Even 100K is tiny data. SQL Server was built to handle multimillion tables even on laptops

Comment: Well the parameters change for the query:
Such as aIDNumber and aDate

It collects records for 40 id's and 20 days.

Also in both cases the database is not used by any other connection. So no update is happening.
Both aIDNumber and aDate are indexed.

Comment: `one would expect that MSSQL can handle this rather easily?` it does. It does with 800K rows and 8M rows without even having to use a special reporting schema. You still haven't explained what you're trying to calculate, or why you execute the same query 800 times instead of running *one* query that returns 800 rows

Comment: If you want to calculate the running total by date, check [this SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842262/sum-of-total-by-date-with-running-total). In both MySQL and SQL Server you can use `SUM (Total) OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RunningTotal` to calculate a running total. Use `GROUP BY` to calculate totals for multiple IDs instead of calculating them one by one, eg `SELECT ProductID, SUM(Total) FROM ... GROUP BY ProductID`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He probably runs same query except for some parts like dates and ids. because... reasons. I'm guessing there's some script which loops some IDs and returns one row per ID. I would say 800 concurrent connection might put some pressure on sql server though

Comment: @siggemannen it's obvious the query is repeated multiple times for different ID values. The question is *why*. That's what needs to get fixed. "Reasons" isn't an excuse

Comment: Well the application collects a sum of aNumber which usually results in 4 or 8.
It does this per day and per aIDNumber.
With 40 aIDNumbers and 20 days, it comes to 800 times this query.

Unfortunately I don't have any influence on the way it collects this date but I'm rather surprised that this was running just fine in MySQL but has such issues in MSSQL.

Comment: Why can't you just upload the 40 and 20 parameters and do it in one batch? Anyway we can't answer this without seeing the full index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: the strange part is why it's slow even though you run in sequence. SQL Server shouldn't need any sort of cool down period. Can you run "Activity monitor" and see if you see any strange IO or waits going up. Perhaps it's doing a lot of STATISTICS updates even though it shouldn't. Or you have some query store which does a lot of flushing. Or you are ruining the query plan cache. Could you perhaps try parametrizing the query or add OPTION (KEEP PLAN)

Comment: How are the queries executed? Does the client code create a new connection for each query? In that case the delay is caused by opening the connection alone.

Comment: @siggemannen I get a large logical read when I open Activity monitor for this query.
I'll try the OPTION (KEEP PLAN) and see if that helps.

Comment: @Charlieface see https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkWko8HX2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the client keeps the connection open.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can improve this query by using a window function instead of a self-join. (If you need tied results then replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.)

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(a.aNumber) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT a.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.aDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM aTable a
    WHERE a.aIDNumber = 59
      AND a.aDate <= '20210331'
      AND a.aDayNumber = 3
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1;
```

Secondly, it looks like the following index would improve the performance massively.

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON aTable
  (aIDNumber ASC, aDayNumber ASC, aDate DESC) INCLUDE (aNumber);
```

The first two columns may be in either order in this case (depends on your other queries). You can also create this as a clustered index, depending on your requirements.

Comment: The MySQL equivalent of that index is `INDEX(aIDNumber, aDayNumber, aDate, Number)`.  (MySQL does not support `INCLUDE`, but this has the same effect.)  (MySQL does not have to mix ASC/DESC to get the same effect and efficiency _in this case_.)

Comment: SQL Server technically doesn't either, it's just there are issues with backwards scans (no parallelism, issues with cardinality estimation). I was targetting SQL Server here as mentioned by OP. Adding `aNumber` into the key means it becomes part of the btree, rather than just in the leaf, so slightly less efficient, a clustered index might be better in MySQL.